# How can I parse this JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, parsing

I have a C# application that reads a player inventory from packets (item name + item id + item count) . I found an website where I can find the item name + quantity/price of the item but its in a JSON format:

```json
"AI Brain": {
  "qty":15,
  "price":1
},
"Air Conditioner": {
  "qty":190,
  "price":1
}
```

So now in my checker I tracked the player inventory and got the item name. I need to use the JSON format to get the quantity and price of the item. How can I do that? There's a lot of items...

Comment: Did you check already some C# JSON libraries?

Comment: yes i did but it was hard to understand and there is AI BRAIN then object idk how to parse it

Comment: are you sure that this is the  json format you get? Normaly your Value 'AI BRAIN' should be assigned to a property eg. Name

Comment: If you put curly brackets around the string you show `"{AI Brain: {... etc... "price" : 1}}"`, then what you show is a JSON object, with to properties (`AI Brain` and `Air Conditioner`} each of which is object valued, with the two objects each having two properties (a number named `qty` and a number named `price`).  With the addition of the curly brackets, any JSON parser should be able to *deserialize* it

Comment: well im not the owner of the api and i told him

Comment: Did any of the answers you got help? At the very least, you'll need to prepend a `"{"` and add a `"}"` to the end of your JSON string to make it proper JSON. Other than that, it's just a matter of *deserializing* the JSON into memory in some way

Comment: @ImBusyGT: there are people putting effort and time in this: please let us know whether or not this helped you

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to deserialize it into a Dictionary.  Here I'm using the NewtonSoft JSON Nuget package.

First create a class that defines the properties of each item:

```
public class TestItem
{
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public int price { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize it into a Dictionary.  Note that you can use either single quotes or double quotes in Javascript (and, as a result, JSON).  I use single quotes here rather than double - it makes the code clearer.  Also note that I added a leading `{` and a trailing `}` to turn your string into legal JSON:

```
 public static void Deserialize()
 {
     var someJson = "{'AI Brain':{ 'qty':15,'price':1},'Air Conditioner':{ 'qty':190,'price':1}}";
     var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, TestItem>>(someJson);
 }
```

The result of this is a Dictionary with two items in it, each having a `string` *Key* and a `TestItem` *Value*.

If you are reading that data from a file, you could leave the quotes alone, and just concatenate a `"{"` to the beginning and a `"}"` to the end after you read the string in.  Something like this:

```
 var fileContents = File.ReadAllText("TestItem.json");
 var fileJson = "{" + fileContents + "}";
 var resultsFromFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, TestItem>>(fileJson);
```

(Assuming that the JSON you show is in a file named `"TestItem.json"`)

This is what the the deserialized object looks like in the debugger:

[image: The deserialized object looks like in the debugger]

Comment: I'll upvote some of this since OP seems to have abandoned this.

Answer (score 1):

check out https://json2csharp.com/ and https://jsonlint.com/ the main problem is this is a terriable design as each item name becomes a new class, instead what you want is some thing like below which encaps and item, and what @Flydog57 said

```
    {
       "Name": "AI Brain",
        "Properties": {
          "qty": 15,
          "price": 1
        }
    },
    {
       "Name": "Air Conditioner",
        "Properties": {
          "qty": 190,
          "price": 1
        }
    }
```

c#

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Properties    {
        public int qty { get; set; } 
        public int price { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public Properties Properties { get; set; } 
    }
```

vs

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class AIBrain    {
        public int qty { get; set; } 
        public int price { get; set; } 
    }

    public class AirConditioner    {
        public int qty { get; set; } 
        public int price { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Root    {
        public AIBrain AIBrain { get; set; } 
        public AirConditioner AirConditioner { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: Or... You could define a class with two `int` properties (`qty` and `price`), lets call it `Item` and then deserialize it into a `Dictionary<string, Item>`

Comment: @Flydog57: indeed a nice alternative

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create the classes (which is good practice btw ), you can use a dynamic and the [Newtonsoft.json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) package:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //note: needed to fix json here
            var json = @"{""AI Brain"":{ ""qty"":15,""price"":1},""Air Conditioner"":{ ""qty"":190,""price"":1}}";
 
            //note2: dynamic is tricky and sensitive for typos.
            dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(json);
 
            //if you know what you want upfront, you can just do
            //Console.WriteLine(obj["AI Brain"].qty);
            //you can also loop them like this:
            foreach (var pair in obj)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pair.Name);

                Console.WriteLine(obj[pair.Name].qty);
                Console.WriteLine(obj[pair.Name].price);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
AI Brain
15
1
Air Conditioner
190
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, using Newtonsoft.Json, dynamics and property discovery:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//...

var json = "{'AI Brain':{ 'qty':15,'price':1},'Air Conditioner':{ 'qty':190,'price':1}}";

dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach(var property in obj.Properties())
    Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name}: {property.Value.qty} @ {property.Value.price:c}");
```